# Replacement for SearchTemplateRequest class in java api client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, apiclient

I am migrating a java application from elastic search high level client to java api client. There is a SearchTemplateRequest class in elastic search java high level client. But I couldn't find any corresponding class in java api client. Can someone help on this? Old code snippet is as below.

```
public SearchTemplateResponse getScriptResponse(String indexName, String scriptName, Map<String, Object> scriptParams) throws IOException {
        SearchTemplateRequest request = null;
        SearchTemplateResponse response = null;
        try {
            SearchTemplateRequest request = new SearchTemplateRequest();
        request.setRequest(new SearchRequest(new String[] { indexName }, trackTotalHitsSourceBuilder()));
        request.setScriptType(ScriptType.STORED);
        request.setScript(scriptName);
        request.setScriptParams(scriptParams);
        request.getRequest().source().trackTotalHits();
        response = getClient().searchTemplate(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return response;
    }


I'm using above code block to get the response of bucket aggregation with script query.
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend read the [Getting Started Java API Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/_getting_started.html).

For create [first connection](https://%20https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/connecting.html) read the link.

Example using script and updateByQuery:

```
Map<String, JsonData> params = Map.of("key", JsonData.of("value"));

Script script = new Script.Builder()
    .stored(StoredScriptId.of(ssi -> ssi.id("script_name").params(params)))
    .build();

UpdateByQueryRequest updateByQueryRequest = UpdateByQueryRequest.of(
    up -> up.index("idx_script_tst")
        .query(Query.of(q -> q.matchAll(MatchAllQuery.of(maq -> maq))))
        .script(script));

var updateResponse = client.updateByQuery(updateByQueryRequest);
```